# deploying graphql apollo server to heroku

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am just about to deploy my graphql apollo server app to heroku so I've added a process.env.PORT inside the listen parameters but this breaks the app when I try to run it locally and gives me the following message:

(node:8179) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT]: options.port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received 5000;.
at validatePort (internal/validators.js:211:11)

```
const { mainCards, animals, categories } = require("./db");
const typeDefs = require("./schema");
const Query = require("./resolvers/Query");
const Animal = require("./resolvers/Animal");
const Category = require("./resolvers/Category");
const Mutation = require("./resolvers/Mutation");
require("dotenv").config();

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers: {
    Query,
    Mutation,
    Animal,
    Category,
  },
  context: {
    mainCards,
    animals,
    categories,
  },
});

// // The `listen` method launches a web server.
server.listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 4000 }).then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

Comment: environment variables are string type, try parsing it to int

Comment: how would i do that please?

Comment: ```server.listen({ port: parseInt(process.env.PORT || 4000, 10) }).then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});```

Comment: Also for debugging try logging the value and type(using typeof) of `process.env.PORT` before starting the server

Comment: perfect :) parsing the .env worked.